# React native: State seems to retain previous state even after reload on the simulator

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, genymotion

I have a code that does something like this:(Pseudo Code)

```
class extends Component{
   constructor(){
       this.state={
         condition1 : false,
         condition2 : false,
         condition3 : false,
         condition4 : false,
       }
       //set all 4 condition states to true once data loading has completed from the store
   }


   render(){

      return(
        if (this.state.condition1 && this.state.condition2 && this.state.condition3 && this.state.condition4)
           Render Main component
        else
           Render loading screen

      );

}



}
```

Basically I have 4 states that are used to check if data has been loaded before loading the main component.Once the Store (from another file) has finished loading the data, it emits an event,causing the 4 states to be set to true, loading the main component.However, once I hit the reload button from the Genymotion emulator, the 4 states remain as true and does not get reset to false, causing the app to load the main component and crash.(Since the data is not ready yet) I have tried resetting all 4 states to false again in the ComponentWillMount method but it seems like the states doesn't get set back to false in time before the main app attempts to load the main component. In which component of the life cycle should I reset the states to false instead? Or should I ignore this issue since it is "unrealistic" to reload the app on an actual device?

Comment: Can you show how you are checking if all states are true?

Comment: Hi I've updated the code to show that

Comment: Do you get any error on chrome console when you turn on remote debugging?

Comment: The only error I got is "cannot read property 0 of undefined", which happens because the data is not ready and the app tries to render it

Comment: Do you have the stack trace to that error? I suggest you put a debugger statement right before the if condition, and check what goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> In which component of the life cycle should I reset the states to
>   false instead?

The docs recommend using `componentWillReceiveProps` to update the state prior to rendering. I've done this for my projects and it works well, though depending on your use case you may need to check whether `newProps` is different than `this.props`.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html

> **componentWillReceiveProps**
>
> Invoked when a component is receiving new props. This method is not
>   called for the initial render.
>
> Use this as an opportunity to react to a prop transition before
>   render() is called by updating the state using this.setState(). The
>   old props can be accessed via this.props. Calling this.setState()
>   within this function will not trigger an additional render.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get around this issue by reducing the number of network fetch requests. It seems that having multiple network requests at the same time can cause instability, even though it is unclear why so.